# Wordpress api json not working with a large amount of posts

Tags: json, wordpress, api, ionic-framework

I am using JSON API plugin with my wordpress page, the array size of the get_recent_posts json is about 250 posts. For instances when i call
http://www.example.org/api/get_recent_posts/ to view theses posts in browser I get a blank page with no errors in the console. However if I limit the such as with 
http://www.example.org/api/get_recent_posts/?count=50 it works fine.

My question is , is this normal ? and how can I get around this , because I want to use an app to display these posts but I can only display a set amount without using custom code to get around this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible your request is timing out and/or PHP is running out of memory. Have you looked at your error logs to see if they reveal anything helpful?

Comment: you can use `<ion-infinite-scroll></ion-infinite-scroll>` tag to display required number of posts in required number of times

Answer (score 0):

As Lucas mentioned in the comments, this is not a Wordpress issue but rather an issue that can be addressed with tweaking your server (more accurately, your PHP) configuration. Try adding the following in your .htaccess file (if your on Apache) and **ed** to allow you to processes the sizes you need.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 64M
```